# why my values are updated after the second click

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my page "exchange converter"
when I want to change my course from the sale to purchase then click button to buy or sell, the rate of change but of the field where output but the result does not change

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        function fn_cross(c) {
            switch (c) {}
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            buyCours();
        });

        function changeCourse(buttonValue) {
            if (buttonValue == ("buyUAH")) {
                buyCours();
            } else {
                sellCours();
            }
        }

        function buyCours() {
            var myData = {
                "operation": "changeCourse",
                "exchangeCall": "buy"
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/ConventerServlet",
                data: {
                    jsonData: JSON.stringify(myData)
                },
                dataType: "json",

                //if received a response from the server
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById('exchangeUSD').value = data.exchangeUSD;
                    document.getElementById('exchangeRUB').value = data.exchangeRUB;
                    document.getElementById('exchangeEUR').value = data.exchangeEUR;
                }
            });
            count($("#inputValue").val())
        }

        function sellCours() {
            var myData = {
                "operation": "changeCourse",
                "exchangeCall": "sell"
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/ConventerServlet",
                data: {
                    jsonData: JSON.stringify(myData)
                },
                dataType: "json",

                //if received a response from the server
                success: function(data) {

                    document.getElementById('exchangeUSD').value = data.exchangeUSD;
                    document.getElementById('exchangeRUB').value = data.exchangeRUB;
                    document.getElementById('exchangeEUR').value = data.exchangeEUR
                }
            });
            count($("#inputValue").val())
        }

        function isNumberKey(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 && charCode != 44 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        function count(inputValue) {

            console.log(inputValue);
            if (inputValue != "") {
                document.getElementById("conventUSD").value = ($("#exchangeUSD").val() * inputValue);
                document.getElementById("conventEUR").value = ($("#exchangeEUR").val() * inputValue);
                document.getElementById("conventRUB").value = ($("#exchangeRUB").val() * inputValue);
            } else {
                var defaultValue = "0.00";
                document.getElementById("conventUSD").value = defaultValue;
                document.getElementById("conventEUR").value = defaultValue;
                document.getElementById("conventRUB").value = defaultValue;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div class="USD">
        <h2 style="text-align: center">UAH</h2> I want
        <input type="button" id="buyUAH" onclick="changeCourse(this.id)" value="Buy">

        <input type="button" id="sellUAH" onclick="changeCourse(this.id)" value="Sell">


        <label for="inputValue"></label>
        <input type="text" value="0.00" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" onkeyup="count(this.value)" onfocus="if (this.value == '0.00') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0.00'; }" id="inputValue" style="width: 100px;margin-bottom: 30px">
        <select id="fn_c1" onchange="fn_cross(this.value)">
            <option selected="" value="840">USD</option>
            <option value="978">EUR</option>
            <option value="643">RUB</option>
            <option value="1">UAH</option>
        </select>
        <br/>Result
        <br/>
        <li>
            <input type="text" readonly value="0.00" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0.00'; }" id="conventUSD"> USD
            <input style="width: 50px" readonly id="exchangeUSD">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" readonly value="0.00" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0.00'; }" id="conventRUB"> RUB
            <input style="width: 50px" readonly id="exchangeRUB">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" readonly value="0.00" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0.00'; }" id="conventEUR"> EUR
            <input style="width: 50px" readonly id="exchangeEUR">
        </li>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Pleas help me with this trouble,show me where the bug and how to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that problem is in yours ajax request.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5r7u3mc/3/) I've just replaced your ajax calls with hardcoded values and everything works fine:

```
// idx definition
var idx = 0;
...
document.getElementById('exchangeUSD').value = 444 + idx;
document.getElementById('exchangeRUB').value = 444 + idx;
document.getElementById('exchangeEUR').value = 444 + idx;
idx++;
```

I hope this would help =)

Comment: but my values are not static, they change when buttons are pressed

Comment: ok, I've changed code on jsfiddle so now values are also changing on each click, and all still works fine